# GUI Framework for research

Tags: python, java, gui, framework, research

I'm working with a Java Simulator and JupyterLab (Python scripts) and currently, I'm launching the experiments directly from Eclipse or the command line, and after I generate plots, tables, etc.

In order to facilitate the executions of the experiments for other people, I want to create a GUI to generate the parameters for the experiments, execute it and show the resulting graphics.

As a suggestion, Vaadin could be an option, but not all the components are free.

Requirements:

- Could be web-based or a desktop application.
- Preferred languages: Java (Swing?) and Python.
- The framework has to be able to execute jars and call JupyterLab scripts (but if not, at least python scripts), and in general, to work like a command line tool interacting with the file system.
- Could be good some compatibility with matplotlib/seaborn or other visual libraries, or even interactive, or at least load images from the file system.